# Change class with angular if response is false

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-ng-class

I'm having some problems how to switch class if request is false. Let me show you my code with explanation.

So this is how my input looks like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="locationName">Location name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="locationName"
           ng-model="locationName">
</div>
```

And this the part of controller where i fetch the response

```
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    console.log(data, status, headers, config);
}).error(function(data) {
    $scope.locationNameError = data.errors.locationName;
});
```

So now i wan't to achieve that when `$scope.locationNameError` is set my class on that desired input has to be `form-group has-error`

So far i was think to make same sort if for example, but this is not working

```
<div ng-if="!locationNameError" class="form-group">
<div ng-if="locationNameError" class="form-group has-error">
```

Am i doing this the wrong way? I wan't to implement the solution with the less code possible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What about using [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ng-class` instead for `ng-if`:

Change:

```
<div ng-if="!locationNameError" class="form-group">
<div ng-if="locationNameError" class="form-group has-error">
```

To:

```
<div ng-class="{'has-error': locationNameError}" class="form-group">
```

Comment: omg, it so easy :D lol. i'm amberesd a little bit :D
Thank you

Comment: Nice to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) directive instead of having two `ng-if`

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': locationNameError}" class="form-group">
```

Answer (score 2):

Ng-class is probably what you're looking for:

`<div data-ng-class="{'has-error': locationNameError}">...</div>`